# Dismiss keyboard with swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

In Messages.app you can dismiss the keyboard down by scrolling the list view. To be clear, it isn't simply responding to a `scrollViewDidScroll` event. The keyboard tracks with your finger as you swipe down. Any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since iOS 7, you can use

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive
```

From the documentation:

> `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive`
>
> The keyboard follows the
>   dragging touch offscreen, and can be pulled upward again to cancel the
>   dismiss.

Comment: Is there an approach without using a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: @Zorayr see my answer

Comment: @Zorayr I just added a scroll view (make sure the view contained inside it has a height larger than the scroll view), and it worked. Set background to clear and hide the scrolling indicator so that the user doesn't see it.

Answer (score 13):

In the XCode, attributes inspector, the `scrollView` has a `Keyboard` attribute. It has 3 options.

- Do not dismiss
- Dismiss on drag
- Dismiss interactive.

[image: UIScrollView properties]

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a `tableView` and **Swift 3** or **Swift 4**, it works by using:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS7, `UIScroll​View` and all classes that inherit from it (including `UITableView`) have a [`keyboard​Dismiss​Mode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619437-keyboarddismissmode) property. With Swift 5 and iOS 12, `keyboard​Dismiss​Mode` has the following declaration:

```
var keyboardDismissMode: UIScrollView.KeyboardDismissMode { get set }
```

> The manner in which the keyboard is dismissed when a drag begins in the scroll view.

Note that [`UIScrollView.KeyboardDismissMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/keyboarddismissmode) is an enum that has `none`, `interactive` and `onDrag` cases.

---

### #1. Set `keyboard​Dismiss​Mode` programmatically

The code snippet below shows a possible implementation of `keyboardDismissMode`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Dismiss keyboard when scrolling the tableView
    tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollView.KeyboardDismissMode.interactive

    /* ... */
}
```

---

### #2. Set `keyboard​Dismiss​Mode` in *storyboard*

As an alternative to the programmatic approach above, you can set the `keyboard​Dismiss​Mode` value for your `UIScrollView`/`UITableView` in the *storyboard*.

1. Select your `UIScrollView` / `UITableView` instance,
2. Select the *Attributes Inspector*,
3. Set the correct value for *Keyboard*.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Without tableview - yes it not a swipe but it doesn't the trick

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```