# How can I pan down to dismiss keyboard?

Tags: ios, user-interface, react-native

In the Messages app, you can "pan down", and the keyboard will follow the touch down until it disappears.

What's the best solution like this for React Native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScrollView` component has a property called [`keyboarddismissmode`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboarddismissmode).

> ### keyboardDismissMode
>
> Determines whether the keyboard gets dismissed in response to a drag.
>
> Cross platform
>
> - `none` (the default), drags do not dismiss the keyboard.
> - `on-drag`, the keyboard is dismissed when a drag begins.
>
> **iOS Only**
>
> - `interactive`, the keyboard is dismissed interactively with the drag and moves in synchrony with the touch; dragging upwards cancels
>     the dismissal. On android this is not supported and it will have the
>     same behavior as 'none'.

I have never used this property but from the description and from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30042568/2315280), I think this is what you are looking for.